# How can I allow port-forwarding for a specific deployment in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, user-roles, rbac

I am trying to allow some users in my org to forward ports to our production namespace in Kubernetes. However, I don't want them to be able to forward ports to all services. I want to restrict access to only certain services. Is this possible?

```
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: allow-port-forward-for-deployment-a
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods/portforward"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "create"]
---
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: allow-port-forward-for-deployment-a
  namespace: production
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: "xyz@org.com"
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: allow-port-forward-for-deployment-a
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

The above set up allows all services, but I don't want that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you can't. [According to the docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#referring-to-resources)

> Resources can also be referred to by name for certain requests through
>   the `resourceNames` list. When specified, requests can be restricted to
>   individual instances of a resource. To restrict a subject to only
>   “get” and “update” a single configmap, you would write:
>
> ```
> apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
> kind: Role
> metadata:
>   namespace: default
>   name: configmap-updater
> rules:
> - apiGroups: [""]
>   resources: ["configmaps"]
>   resourceNames: ["my-configmap"]
>   verbs: ["update", "get"]
> ```
>
> **Note that create requests
>   cannot be restricted by resourceName, as the object name is not known
>   at authorization time. The other exception is deletecollection.**

Since you want to give the user permissions to **create** the forward ports, I don't think you can.

Answer (score 3):

These rules worked for me

```
   kind: Role
    apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
    metadata:
      namespace: default
      name: port-forward
    rules:
    - apiGroups: [""]
      resources: ["pods/portforward"]
      verbs: ["get", "create"]
    - apiGroups: [""]
      resources: ["pods", "services"]
      verbs: ["get", "list"]
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming users already have access to your `kubernetes` cluster and relevant `namespace`. They can simply port-forward local port to a `pod` (resource) port.

How can you do this?
`kubectl port-forward <POD_NAME> <LOCAL_PORT>:<POD_PORT>`

[See Documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/)

**Quoting from the document** - `kubectl port-forward` allows using resource name, such as a `pod` name, to select a matching `pod` to `port forward` to since `Kubernetes v1.10`.

[Refer this article if you wish, this nicely explains when you would need RBAC vs kubectl port-forward](https://medium.com/@ManagedKube/kubernetes-rbac-port-forward-4c7eb3951e28)
`RBAC` could have been useful only when, you wanted `person` or a `group of people` only to `port-forward` for any services in a relevant `namespace` in your `kubernetes` cluster.

Answer (score 0):

#### Workaround A: StatefulSets and resourceNames

It is possible to restrict port forwarding to a pod with a specific name. `resourceNames` refer to resources, not subresources:

```yaml
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: allow-port-forward-for-deployment-a
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods/portforward"]
  resourceNames: ["my-app"]
  verbs: ["create"]
```

A [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) generates predictable pod names, but is different from a ReplicaSet and might not fit your use case.

#### Workaround B: Jump pod and NetworkPolicy

Sketch:

- A StatefulSet that runs `kubectl port-forward services/my-service` inside the cluster (JUMP).
- A NetworkPolicy which restricts traffic from pods belonging to JUMP to the target service
- RBAC which restricts creation of subresource portforward to the pods of JUMP up to a predefined maximum number of replicas `resourceNames: ["jump-0", "jump-1", ..., "jump-N"]`.